# Deleting using a join without where

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. adjustments and transactions. I want to delete all loan adjustments contained in transactions.
There are three corresponding fields to it. Date. ID. Value.

There are no fks. I used a delete join but it didn't work.

However when using a join it asks for me to specify data for trans.id.  Trans.date. Trans.value. Is there anyway to forgo the where as I want to delete all of the related entries from adjustments in transactions.

Comment: What is this `ID` column is it a referencing column to some column in `adjustments` table ?

Comment: So Date, ID, and Value are what relate these two tables together?  and are all adjustments "LOAN" adjustments

Comment: Share the query you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete all the row from `Transactions` table referencing in  `Adjustments` table. There should be a column in Transactions table which references to some column in Adjustments table.

Suppose the `ID` column in your `Transactions` table References some `ID` column in `Adjustments` table then you would write this delete query something like this...

```
DELETE FROM Transactions
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
               FROM Adjustments
               WHERE ID = Transactions.ID)
```